# Failing to insert data from a form into a database using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im trying to get my data from a form into a database, i've used a tutorial online to do so, everything works right to the point where it has to actually get it to the database i just cant find what's wrong with it

```
    $kenteken = $_POST['kenteken'];
    $werkplaatsnr = $_POST['werkplaatsnr'];
    $datum = $_POST['datum'];
    $medewerker = $_POST['medewerker'];

    $pdoQuery = "INSERT INTO `WPOnderhoud`(`kenteken`, `werkplaats`, `datum`, `medewerker`) VALUES (:kenteken,:werkplaatsnr,:datum,:medewerker)";

    $pdoResult = $pdoConnect->prepare($pdoQuery);

    $pdoExec = $pdoResult->execute(array(":kenteken"=>$kenteken,":werkplaatsnr"=>$werkplaatsnr,":datum"=>$datum,":medewerker"=>$medewerker));

    if($pdoExec)
    {
    echo 'Onderhoudsbeurt ingevoerd';

    } else {
        echo 'Er ging iets mis';
    }
}
```

this is my code, it's not all because above it is the connection to the database but since it does connect i don't see any wrong in it.

the $pdoConnect is the database connection

this is the mentioned form:

```
<form action="onderhoud.php" method="POST">

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Kenteken</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="kenteken">
</div>  

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Merk</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="merk">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Werkplaats nr</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="werkplaatsnr">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Datum</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="datum">
</div>                                  

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Medewerker</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="state_id">
        <option>R. Krol</option>
        <option>B. de Vries</option>
        <option>J. Jansen</option>
        <option>P .Bakker</option>
    </select>                   
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" name="insert" class="btn btn-primary">Invoeren</button>
</div>     

</form>
```

Comment: Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: Yes viewing the error will help a lot in understanding the problem

Comment: Your select input doesn't have a name, so it's not passing in, so `$medewerker = $_POST['medewerker'];` would throw an error.

Comment: how stupid of me to forget to add a name, that's why it didn't work thanks :)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try below,

```
$pdoExec = $pdoConnect->prepare("INSERT INTO WPOnderhoud values('',?,?,?,?)");
$pdoExec ->bindParam(1,$kenteken);
$pdoExec ->bindParam(2,$werkplaatsnr);
$pdoExec ->bindParam(3,$datum);
$pdoExec ->bindParam(4,$medewerker);
$pdoExec ->execute();
```

Hope will help you.

Comment: Try this why? Why are you inserting an empty string?